# UI does not refresh when TextEditor changed

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following code. When text changed, the overlaid content does not removed?

```
ZStack {
   TextEditor(text: $text)

   if text.isEmpty {
       Text("Content")
   }
}
```

Initially the overlaid content is shown, but if I continue to type on TextEditor, the content remains on screen. I have also check text.count == 0 and the result is the same.

Here's the screenshot - the $text in TextEditor (yellow background) is obviously not empty. (Tested on iPadOS/iOS 14.6 and 14.7 beta)

[image: TextEditor]

Comment: Can you show a complete code to reproduce the issue? As far as I put your code into the body of ContentView, `Text("Content")` is hidden behind the TextEditor whether or not `text` is empty.

Comment: Hi, sorry about that. The code is quite long so I can't paste all here. But here's the reason for text hiding, as I have this in my code:     init() { UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear }

Comment: I will reverse the order to see the issue.

Comment: Your code snapshot works fine with Xcode 12.5 / iOS 14.5. Please provide complete reproducible example and in which env do you test it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tested it on 14.6/14.7 beta and the Content text does not go away as I am typing on the TextEditor. Seems like $text does not refresh the other views. I am using iPhone 12 mini and iPad mini for testing.

Comment: Thanks, I found the issue and it is related to GeometryReader somehow. Probably a bug in 14.6/14.7.

Answer (score 0):

updated answer showing that as the text becomes empty (or not) the view changes:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var text: String = ""

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TextEditor(text: $text)
            .overlay(text.isEmpty ? Text("Content isEmpty") : Text(""))
            .frame(width:222, height: 111).border(Color.red)  // <-- testing
        
        text.isEmpty ? Text("text is empty") : Text("text NOT empty")
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. But this does not solve the issue I faced that changes in $text (add/remove text from Text Editor) does not refresh the view. Anything in the view that uses text.isEmpty (or text.count == 0) does not work. For example, I disabled some icons using text.isEmpty and they don't work.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Let us know if this does not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue (and the solution):
I have a GeometryReader at the beginning of the body, once I removed it, this issue gone away and everything works as expected.
This might be a SwiftUI bug.

Comment: could be a bug, but probably not. Show us the code you are using instead of just a little bit of it.

Comment: The code is quite long, and the only difference between working and not working is GeometryReader in the body - which should not cause issue like this.

Comment: I've put a GeometryReader in my answer code and all is still working well.